# How to create schema with varchar(50) in pyspark or cast as varchar(50) in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, databricks

```
schema = StructType([StructField("column_name", StringType(), True)
```

In my target system for column they are assigning 50 length and i have created schema of StringType in databricks while loading data from databricks to target database by default it is allocating nvarchar(4000) length because of this cpu consumption is more.how to handle  in databricks how to make nvarchar to varchar in databrciks

Comment: see `VarcharType` [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datatypes.html). you can't use this in functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VarcharType` type like below.

```
schema = StructType([StructField("column_name", VarcharType(50), True)
```